# Where to put Navigation Controller in Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, xcode

Say, I have a `Login` screen, `Contacts` screen and `Settings` screen.
`Login` screen doesn't seem to be used frequently in the app so I suspect it is fine to exclude it from the main navigation flow.

Thus I set `Login` screen as the app entry point, then put all the rest screens as the children of the Navigation Controller. This way I do login process, then pass the control to the Navigation Controller and it does all the in-app navigation in a regular manner.

I am concerned if I am doing it right way, as probably I should make the Navigation Controller as the entry point and then dispatch all the navigation, even for `Login` screen, with it.

Is it supposed to have a single Navigation Controller inside an app? If so, is it supposed to have it as the parent dispatcher for all the scenes or is it fine to have some scenes put independent?

Here is the current config:

[image: Scenes]

Answer (score 0):

It's fine to embed multiple navigation controllers.  In your case, I wouldn't think there would be any issues with not having the initial controller embedded in a nav controller-- getting back to the log in screen would be as simple as using an unwind segue.  Alternatively, making the first VC a nav controller also presents no problem, but in your case it would eliminate the need for a second nav controller, based on your current configuration.  I find multiple navigation controllers most useful when I'm using container views, and want to swap out VCs within that container.

That's my 2 cents.